# JavaScript event IE issue when event is a global variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, dom-events

I have a js function which accepts event object as an argument.
In that js function, I assign that event object to a global variable.
In another ajax callback I access that global variable (event object).

My Question:
the key code value of that event in both methods are same in both methods in Firefox,
but it gives different value in IE 7?
for example,if key code is 75, Firefox returns 75 in both methods.
but IE7 gives 75 in method-1 and 0 in method-2

Why does it behave like this?

Comment: Can you post your code here ?

Comment: You likely want to store the ID of the event's srcElement/target instead

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass the event object with IE, you need to create a new object and make a copy the properties that you want to use.

Comment: hai i have worked as you said.Now it works fine.Your answer is really useful. thanks a lot...